# How to test IR sensor on OSMC?

Tags: sensor, remote, lirc

I've tried to follow some tutorials on installing an IR sensor to GPIO, with the goal of using an old Xbox remote with OSMC. They basically say to connect it up to pins 1 (3V3), 6 (GND) and 12 (GPIO 18). My sensor is for 4.5V, tsop1556, that I salvaged from a broken Xbox dongle, so I've also tried making it work on 5V.

Some tutorials say to disable GPIO IR support in Kodi to be able to test the sensor with `mode2`, but when I disable it I can no longer `modprobe lirc_rpi` after a reboot. Instead I get `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'lirc_rpi': No such device`. I don't know what to make of that.

I disable it in `My OSMC → Pi Config → Hardware Support → Enable LIRC GPIO Support`

One osmc dev said to do

```
sudo systemctl stop lircd_helper@lirc0
mode2 -d /dev/lirc0
```

With that I get the same results, i.e. nothing shows up after running mode2 and pressing some buttons on a remote.

The IR receiver seems to work when testing it with batteries and a LED.

The ir sensor pins:

Gnd

Vs

Out

The configs I tried:
(Numbers are pi pins)

Gnd — 6

Vs — 1 (3V3)

Out — 12

Not working: `mode2 -d /dev/lirc0` gives no output. Not unexpected, since sensor minimum voltage is 4.5.

Gnd — 6

Vs — 2 (5V)

Out — 1 kOhm — 12 — 1.2 kOhm — 6

Not working: `mode2 -d /dev/lirc0` gives no output. Not sure what I did wrong here. I also tried with two 1k resistors.

Comment: You could try [piscope](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html) or [monitor GPIO](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_monitor_py) with the IR connected and pulses being received.  If neither show activity it suggests the IR is bust.

Comment: @joan Thank you for the suggestions, I'll definitely check them out.

Comment: @joan Monitor GPIO didn't show any activity. Measuring GND and OUT in the second setup shows they're 0.3 V apart. I was under the impression that OUT would be low only when the sensor receives a signal. Does this mean it's broken? It worked with a battery and LED... :-/

Comment: Nvm, got it answered in separate question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a 56 KHz sensor with more tolerance for lower source voltages (< 3.3 V) worked much better.

A few layers of printer paper is needed to stop interference (phantom input) from the TV's CCFL backlight PWM when at low backlight levels.